# How to fill in a Numpy 4D array using nested For loops in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, nested

I have a 4 Dimensional array, where the first 3 dimensions are x,y,z locations and the 4th one is Time.

I have to make a filter for (each voxel in) this array then substract each filter from each voxel and then fill in the new filtered values in a new array called data_4d_filt!

I'm having trouble with figuring out the right indexing inside my nested Forloop, because it's 4D, I've lost track of where I am and what I'm doing!

I don't really know if I should index my Filter or the to be filled data_4d_filt array?

So in the code below should I do this:

```
Filter[i, ii, iii] = gaussian_filter(data_4d[i, ii, iii], 25)
data_4d_filt = data_4d - Filter
```

or this:

```
Filter[i] = gaussian_filter(data_4d[i], 25)
data_4d_filt = data_4d - Filter
```

or this:

```
Filter = gaussian_filter(data_4d, 25)
data_4d_filt[i, ii, iii] = data_4d[i, ii, iii] - Filter
```

Can anyone help me with this plz???

```
data_4d = nib.load('unfiltered_data_ds.nii.gz').get_data()
print("Shape of the original 4D fMRI scan: %s" % (data_4d.shape,))

# Here, we pre-allocate a matrix of the same shape as data_4d, in which
# you need to store the filtered timeseries
data_4d_filt = np.zeros(data_4d.shape)

# Start loop across X-dimension
for i in range(data_4d.shape[0]):

# Start loop across Y-dimension
for ii in range(data_4d.shape[1]):

    # Start loop across Z-dimension
    for iii in range(data_4d.shape[2]):
        # Filter the timeseries for voxel at location X=i, Y=ii, Z=iii and store it
        # using an appropriate index in the pre-allocated variable data_4d_filt!



        # My CODE HERE
        Filter[i, ii, iii] = gaussian_filter(data_4d[i, ii, iii], 25)
        data_4d_filt = data_4d - Filter
```